# Mono For Android: java.lang.NullPointerException on StartActivityForResult

Tags: c#, android, nullpointerexception, xamarin.android

I have a problem regarding StartActivityForResult. I have a form which comes from a webservice, that occasionally results in a field that requires to open up cam take a pic, display it on the view and send it back over.

The problem is I always get a nondescriptive Java.Lang.NullPointerException error on my StartActivityForResult.

And here is the code

**PrevzemVozila.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Data;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Provider;

namespace UUIDev
{
[Activity(Label = "Prevzem vozila v servis", NoHistory = true, Icon="@drawable/Icon",     ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class PrevzemVozila : Activity
{
    si.rcg.hat._hat_Tablet chk = new si.rcg.hat._hat_Tablet();
    Java.IO.File _file;
    PackageManager _pm;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Prevzem);

        _pm = this.PackageManager;

        //Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateAlwaysVisible);

        var Ticket = Intent.GetStringExtra("sentTicket") ?? "";
        var FormIdStr = Intent.GetStringExtra("sentFormId") ?? "";
        var EventNoStr = Intent.GetStringExtra("sentEventNo") ?? "";

        int FormId = int.Parse(FormIdStr);
        int EventNo = int.Parse(EventNoStr);

        DataSet GetSingleEvent = new DataSet();
        GetSingleEvent = chk.GetSingleEvent(Ticket, FormId, EventNo);

        IList<Prevzem> listPrevzem = new JavaList<Prevzem>();



        var lstPrevzem = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstPrevzem);
        var prevzemAdapter = new PrevzemAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.ListPrevzem, new JavaList<Prevzem>());
        lstPrevzem.Adapter = prevzemAdapter;

        foreach (DataRow row in GetSingleEvent.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            var item = new Prevzem();
            item.IdRec = row["IdRec"].ToString();
            if (item.IdRec.Equals(""))
                item.IdRec = null;

            item.FieldId = row["FieldId"].ToString();
            if (item.FieldId.Equals(""))
                item.FieldId = null;

            item.FieldDesc = row["FieldDesc"].ToString();
            if (item.FieldDesc.Equals(""))
                item.FieldDesc = null;

            item.FieldType = row["FieldType"].ToString();
            if (item.FieldType.Equals(""))
                item.FieldType = null;

            item.isReadOnly = row["isReadOnly"].ToString();
            if (item.isReadOnly.Equals(""))
                item.isReadOnly = null;

            item.FieldValue = row["FieldValue"].ToString();
            if (item.FieldValue.Equals(""))
                item.FieldValue = null;

            item.FieldTextValue = row["FieldTextValue"].ToString();
            if (item.FieldTextValue.Equals(""))
                item.FieldTextValue = null;

            item.OptBox_Options = row["OptBox_Options"].ToString();
            if (item.OptBox_Options.Equals(""))
                item.OptBox_Options = null;


            listPrevzem.Add(item);

            RunOnUiThread(() => {prevzemAdapter.Add(item);});
        }
    }

    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void OnGetCam(Intent _intent, IList<ResolveInfo> _avalableActivities)
    {
        if (_avalableActivities != null && _avalableActivities.Count > 0)
        {
            var dir = new Java.IO.File(
                Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "RCG_Foto");

            if (!dir.Exists())
            {
                dir.Mkdirs();
            }

            _file = new Java.IO.File(dir, String.Format("avto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

            _intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(_file));

            this.StartActivityForResult(_intent, 5);
        }
    }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageSending);

            // make it available in the gallery
            var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            var contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(_file);
            mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
            SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

            // display in ImageView
            var fotka = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, contentUri);
            imageView.SetImageBitmap(fotka);
            fotka.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**PrevzemAdapter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Data;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Provider;

namespace UUIDev
{
    [Activity(Label = "Prevzem Adapter")]
    public class PrevzemAdapter : ArrayAdapter<Prevzem>
    {
        int resource;

        PrevzemVozila pa;

        Intent availIntent;

        IList<ResolveInfo> availableActivities;



        Context p_context = null;

        //Initialize adapter
        public PrevzemAdapter(Context context, int resource, IList<Prevzem> items)
            : base(context, resource, items)
        {
            this.resource = resource;
            this.p_context = context;
            this.AvailIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            this.AvailActivities = p_context.PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(AvailIntent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LinearLayout view;

            //Get our items
            var item = GetItem(position);

            //Inflate the view
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                view = new LinearLayout(Context);
                var inflater = Context.LayoutInflaterService;
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(inflater);
                vi.Inflate(resource, view, true);
            }

            else
            {
                view = (LinearLayout)convertView;
            }

            var FieldDesc = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtFieldDesc);
            FieldDesc.Text = item.FieldDesc != null ? item.FieldDesc : "";

            var IdRec = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtIdRec);
            IdRec.Text = item.IdRec != null ? item.IdRec : "";

            var FieldId = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtFieldId);
            FieldId.Text = item.FieldId != null ? item.FieldId : "";

            var FieldTextValue = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editVal);
            FieldTextValue.Text = item.FieldTextValue != null ? item.FieldTextValue : "";

            var ButtonValue = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            ButtonValue.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone ? ViewStates.Gone : ViewStates.Gone;

            var CamImage = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageSending);
            CamImage.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone ? ViewStates.Gone : ViewStates.Gone;

            var SpinnerValue = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerVal);



            bool isReadOnly = bool.Parse(item.isReadOnly);

            if (isReadOnly == true)
            {
                FieldTextValue.Enabled = false;
                SpinnerValue.Enabled = false;


            }
            else
            {
                FieldTextValue.Enabled = true;
                SpinnerValue.Enabled = true;
            }

            // if field is TextBOX_INT
            if (item.FieldType == "TextBOX_INT")
            {
                FieldTextValue.InputType = InputTypes.ClassNumber;   
            }

            // if field is TextBOX or TextBOX_INT or TextAREA
            if (item.FieldType == "TextBOX" || item.FieldType == "TextBOX_INT" || item.FieldType == "TextAREA")
            {
                FieldTextValue.SetSingleLine(true);

                FieldTextValue.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Visible;

                SpinnerValue.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone ? ViewStates.Gone : ViewStates.Gone;
            }

            // if field is TextAREA
            if (item.FieldType == "TextAREA")
            {
                FieldTextValue.InputType = InputTypes.ClassText;

                FieldTextValue.SetSingleLine(false);
            }

            // if field is ComboBOX or OptionBox
            if (item.FieldType == "ComboBOX" || item.FieldType == "OptionBOX")
            {
                FieldTextValue.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone ? ViewStates.Gone : ViewStates.Gone;

                SpinnerValue.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Visible;
                List<string> entries = new List<string>();

                String rawXML = item.OptBox_Options;

                StringReader stream = null;
                XmlTextReader reader = null;

                DataSet xmlDS = new DataSet();
                stream = new StringReader(rawXML);
                // Load the XmlTextReader from the stream
                reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
                xmlDS.ReadXml(reader);

                DataSet myOPTvalues = new DataSet();
                myOPTvalues = xmlDS;

                foreach (DataRow row in myOPTvalues.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    var optItem = new PrevzemSpin();
                    optItem.FieldValue = row["FieldValue"].ToString();
                    if (optItem.FieldValue.Equals(""))
                        optItem.FieldValue = null;

                    optItem.FieldTextValue = row["FieldTextValue"].ToString();
                    if (optItem.FieldTextValue.Equals(""))
                        optItem.FieldTextValue = null;


                    entries.Add(optItem.FieldTextValue);
                    SpinnerValue.Tag = optItem.FieldValue;
                }

                var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(p_context, Android.Resource.Layout.SelectDialogItem, entries);
                adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SelectDialogSingleChoice);
                SpinnerValue.Adapter = adapter;

                if (SpinnerValue.Adapter.Count.Equals(2))
                {
                    SpinnerValue.SetSelection(1);
                }                
            }

            // if field is Picture_REQ
            //if (item.FieldType == "Picture_REQ")
            // {
                ButtonValue.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Visible;
                CamImage.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Visible;
                FieldTextValue.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone ? ViewStates.Gone : ViewStates.Gone;
                SpinnerValue.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone ? ViewStates.Gone : ViewStates.Gone;



                ButtonValue.Click += delegate
                {
                    pa = new PrevzemVozila();
                    if (pa != null)
                    {
                        pa.OnGetCam(this.AvailIntent, this.AvailActivities);
                    }
                };
            //}

            return view;
        }

        public IList<ResolveInfo> AvailActivities
        {
            set { this.availableActivities = value; }
            get { return this.availableActivities; }
        }

        public Intent AvailIntent
        {
            set { this.availIntent = value; }
            get { return this.availIntent; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Based upon** 
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Recipes/Other_UX/Camera_Intent/Take_a_Picture_and_Save_Using_Camera_App

Comment: Well check if _intent isn't null before calling _intent.PutExtra

Comment: Not null :/ -> Contains: {Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE }}

Comment: Could you please post the exception stack trace, it may help

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://pastebin.com/VZwRJLh3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matter was resolved some time ago with a patch provided by Xamarin.